# Efficient per-frame constants in shaders

Tags: opengl

I have some variables that stay the same during the entire frame and will be used by a large number of the various shaders I use (several dozens). These include things such as the various transforms of the camera, light source data, etc.

The main options to provide this data to all the shaders (at least that I can think of) are:

- Just give each shader uniforms for the data and set all uniforms manually when they're required
- Use buffers, such as

  - Uniform Buffer Objects
  - Shader Storage Buffer Objects
  - Buffer Textures

Which of these options is generally the most performance efficient, and why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uniform buffer objects (the GL equivalent of D3D constant buffers) are designed just for such things and will probably give you the best results.

First of all, you will have lower CPU overhead by filling a buffer yourself and uploading it to the GPU all at once, than by setting each uniform with its own individual GL call (which also makes the driver do some work to track changed uniforms and upload them when needed, etc).

Moreover, UBOs can be shared across multiple shaders if desired, and only need to be filled out and uploaded once, rather than per-shader.

As for the various types of buffers, GPUs and their drivers often have optimizations for UBOs that don't apply to buffer textures or SSBOs.  For example, when executing a warp/wavefront, when you read a value from a UBO, the read could be issued just once and the result broadcast to all threads; but reading from a buffer texture or SSBO might issue a read for each thread, which would be less efficient.  Also, GPUs often have a special memory cache dedicated just to uniforms, while reading from a buffer texture or SSBO would go through the texture cache and potentially conflict with other texture accesses also done by the shader.

Answer (score 1):

Given that nothing has the absolute performance superiority. But rather each one was designed to give you a convenience (read:performance but not absolutely) in certain operations.

**Buffer textures** are used to store larger data buffers (like huge matrices) and be accessed directly by shaders, without the filtering and image specific operations that are used on regular textures.

While, the biggest difference between a **uniform block** and a **shader storage block** is that your shader can write into the shader storage block, so if you are not going to write on them use a Uniform Buffer Objects ( so in your case you should use them ).

I think of the difference as a semantic one, so I would say use each one for it's original purpose.